# Using random numbers to delete random lines of a file. Fortran90

Tags: random, fortran90, delete-row

I've been struggling with a problem, so if anyone could offer any advice or examples it would be really appreciated. Using Fortran90.

**Purpose of program:**

To delete random lines from a file, at a quantity of my choosing. The best way I could think to do that was using random numbers to correspond to a line number.

**What it does at the moment:**

Generates new random numbers each time and outputs them to a separate file.

**Problems:**

(1) it doesn't generate integers that could correspond to a line number.
          (2) I don't know how to make the leap into using those numbers to delete lines from a file.

```
program random1
implicit none
integer :: i, seed, removed
real :: r
open (unit=10,file='random.dat')
removed=5

call init_random_seed() 
do i=1,removed
call random_number(r)
write(10,*) r
end Do

end program random1

subroutine init_random_seed()
        integer :: i,n,clock
        integer, dimension(:),allocatable :: seed

        call random_seed(size=n)
        allocate(seed(n))

        call system_clock(count=clock)

        seed=clock+37*(/(i-1,i=1,n)/)
        call random_seed(put=seed)

        deallocate(seed)
end subroutine
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some fragments of an answer.  First some declarations

```
integer :: num_lines ! number of lines in file
integer :: ix        ! loop index variable
real :: fraction     ! what fraction of lines are to be deleted
logical, dimension(:), allocatable :: lines_index
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: rands
```

now some executables

```
read(*,*) num_lines  ! or figure it out some other way
read(*,*) fraction   ! likewise 

allocate(rands(num_lines)) ! no error checking
call random_number(rands)
allocate(lines_index(num_lines), source=rands<fraction)      ! no error checking
```

and now where `lines_index(ix)` is false you can delete line `ix` of your file.  As to actually deleting lines from a file, I suggest that you read the file line-by-line and only write out, to another file, those lines which are not to be deleted.  Something like this might work

```
do ix = 1, num_lines
    read(infile,*) aline
    if(lines_index(ix)) write(outfile,*) aline
end do
```

Note that the approach I've taken doesn't guarantee that 20% (or whatever you set `fraction` to be) lines will be deleted, only that that is the most likely number of lines which will be deleted.  If you want to guarantee that `n` lines will be deleted, do something like

```
integer :: num_lines ! number of lines in file
integer :: ix, jx    ! loop index variables
integer :: n         ! number of lines to delete
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: lines_index    ! line numbers for deletion
real :: rand

read(*,*) n

allocate(del_ix(n))         

do ix = 1,n
    call random_number(rand)
    lines_index(ix) = 1.0+num_lines*rand   ! lines_index(ix) will be between 1 and num_lines
end do
```

This approach doesn't guarantee that the same line won't be selected for deletion more than once, you'll have to write some code to deal with that situation.  Then carry on:

```
do ix = 1, num_lines
    read(infile,*) aline
    if(any(lines_index==ix)) then
        ! do not write the line
    else
        write(outfile,*) aline
    end if
end do
```